# NestJS - Microservices - Kafka Exception Handling

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

I'm using NestJS to implement a microservice architecture, I'm using CLIENT app using NestJS,

The client app receives a rest request and sends to Kafka to get the result

```
  try {
     const pattern = 'findDoctors';
     const payload = body;
     const doctors = await lastValueFrom(
       this.client.send(pattern, payload).pipe(timeout(50000)),
     );
     return doctors;
   } catch (e) {
     console.log(e);
     throw new Error(e);
   }
```

And in the microservice side (Hybrid Application for now, will remove the rest apis later)

```
 @MessagePattern('findDoctors')
 findDoctors(@Payload() message): any {
   return this.doctorService.searchForDoctors(message.value);
 }
```

```
async searchForDoctors(data): Promise<any[]> {
   this.logger.info('Started search for doctors job');
   throw 'Not Found';
}
```

After i throw the exception i get in the logs

```
node:17720) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, ArrayBuffer, or Array or an Array-like Object. Received an instance of Object
   at Function.from (buffer.js:330:9)
   at ServerKafka.assignErrorHeader (C:\Users\Desktop\Projects\node_modules\@nestjs\microservices\server\server-kafka.js:137:73)
   at ServerKafka.sendMessage (C:\Users\Desktop\Projects\node_modules\@nestjs\microservices\server\server-kafka.js:119:14)
   at C:\Users\Desktop\Projects\node_modules\@nestjs\microservices\server\server-kafka.js:81:31
   at C:\Users\Desktop\node_modules\@nestjs\microservices\server\server.js:46:31
   at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11)
(node:17720) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 3)
(node:17720) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

and the client side just waits to timeout and never receive an exception response from the micro service

Tried using RpcException  but it's the same

Comment: What are you expecting Kafka to "return" here from a Producer client?

Comment: the 'not found' error, i tried using throw new RpcException('Invalid credentials.'); too but it only works with return new RpcException and not throw so i can't use filters

Comment: My point is that kafka producers don't "search". You'd be sending a request that's inserted into some topic. Somewhere else needs to be a _consumer client_ that's reading that search request event, and doing some processing on it... However, Kafka is not a proper replacement for request-response models, and it'd be preferred if you used an actual database indexed by doctor id/name, for example

Comment: Can you please share the full content of `server-kafka.js`? Or at least tell us what is line 137 mentioned in the error?

Comment: it's more of a nestjs and typescript issue but using Kafka so it's not the main purpose here, thank you

Comment: Alright, then, removing the tag. Glad you found the error.

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer

used

```
return new RpcException('not found');
```

instead of

```
throw new RpcException('not found')
```

throwing the exception needs an exception filter to catch it

```
@Catch(RpcException)
export class ExceptionFilter implements RpcExceptionFilter<RpcException> {
  catch(exception: RpcException, host: ArgumentsHost): Observable<any> {
    return throwError(exception.getError());  
  }
}
```

and in the client side you can catch the error when using filters and return a normal http exception, or use filters on that too

```
 @Post('/search')
  async findAll(@Body() body) {
    console.log('Sending kafka msg');
    try {
      const doctors = await this.doctorService.findDoctors(body);
      return doctors;
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e)
      throw new HttpException({
        status: '500',
        error: e.message,
      }, 500)
    }
  }
```